# Delete entity with FK

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, primary-key, sql-delete

I want to delete entity with FK. This is my code:

```
var db = new DeresyDBEntities();
var item=db.Items.Where(p => p.ID == ItemId).SingleOrDefault();
if(item!=null)
{
    foreach (var tag in db.ItemsTags.Where(p => p.ItemId == ItemId))
        db.ItemsTags.Remove(tag);
    foreach (var comment in db.ItemsComments.Where(p => p.ItemId == ItemId))
        db.ItemsComments.Remove(comment);
    foreach (var rate in db.ItemsVotes.Where(p => p.ItemId == ItemId))
        db.ItemsVotes.Remove(rate);

    db.Items.Remove(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return true;
}
```

There is any other way to delete it?

Comment: Shouldn't all of those items be removed automatically when you delete the item?  That's if they are foreign keyed to the item

Comment: Can't you use Cascade Delete on the DB?

Comment: I got Linq Exception when try to remove only item. How to Turn on Cascade delete?

Comment: Are you in control of the database? and what is the error you receive?

Comment: Yes I can control Database, I got error "Items contains FK to .... "

Comment: where's the rest of the error?

Comment: I can't write all error now becouse error is about removing entity with Forgein keys.

Comment: I'm guessing you are missing another foreign key reference from one of the other tables, not 'Item'.  Does ItemTags, ItemComments, or ItemVotes have any foreign keys?  That is where I'm guessing you're missing the FK.

Comment: If you have an EDMX, define the cascade delete on the relationships + make sure out is set in the FK definitions in the DB.